# Thymeleaf layout using decorator does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am developing an application that uses the latest version of spring boot and thymeleaf,
I want to use the layout functionality of thymeleaf
my layout is on page layout.html and other page is index.html

\src\main\resources\templates\layout.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
...
```

\src\main\resources\templates\index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security"
layout:decorate="~{layout.html}">
```

In the navigator i have the same thing as if thymeleaf does not replace layout.html

Comment: And you have the layout dialect added as a dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of `layout:fragment` would be required to replace the content.
Reference with example https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html